# Junit test with WebDriver fails an ant run

Tags: maven, selenium, ant, junit, selenium-webdriver

I am running a junit test which uses WebDriver to open a google page(It is in a package testing.com and the file is called GoogleTest. It passes in eclipse and when I give the command "mvn test" at the command line it passes. However when I run an ant build using the command line and fire the "ant run" command I am getting the following output-[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0,
The reported error is:

```
Error   INSTANCE

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<init>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:52)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<init>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:56)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<clinit>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:46)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:72)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:84)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<clinit>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:59)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalConnectionFactory.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:487)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:147)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:136)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:112)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.getClientConnectionManager(HttpClientFactory.java:68)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.<init>(HttpClientFactory.java:54)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:99)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:82)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:93)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:191)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
at testing.com.GoogleTest.testGoogle(GoogleTest.java:20)
    10.578
```

I would really appreciate your input as I have tried many things but still get same error.

My java jdk path is fine- has been checked a few times, I added all the SELENIUM jar files to the CLASSPATH including the Selenium SERVER standalone jar file as suggested by another post.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `mvn clean test`. Also, what is the advantage of mixing Ant and Maven in the same project?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Java,Selenium and ant you are using?

It seems like a version mismatch or version compatibility issue.I recommend you to check whether you have **two different versions of Selenium available in your classpath** if yes make it one.Similarly you should make sure that **only single and compatible ant version** is set on your system.

Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply -I am using version 1.9.2 apache ant, java jdkl1.7.0_60 and Selenium 2.42.2. I  checked class path and I have added latest version of Selenium Client jars and StandAlone server jars to it-Added class path through command line - I can only find one version of ant and

Comment: Problem got sorted - I installed junit on my machine c:\junit-and set the junit_home to c:\juniT in environmnent variables. (I am using WINDOWS 7).I changed my build.xml file - used a build.xml from Web which includes references to Selenium Standalone Server -e.g." <property name="selenium_server_standalone_2_42_2_jar" value="${lib.dir}/selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar"/>"
 In my own build.xml I was referencing the Selenium jars through the maven repository- .M2\REPOSITORY